# WIll DAC allow me to run queries on a pegged SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Background:

We have a SQL Server instance that has pegged out a few times in the last few weeks.  No one has been able to figure out how to get on and kill processes so they have just been rebooting the server (eek!).

I ended up [posting on here](https://serverfault.com/questions/244783/how-to-look-at-what-is-going-on-in-a-pegged-sql-server-instance) in an effort to get access to the server when it's in this state and was directed to the DAC.  From what I've read this will allow me to connect the next time it gets pegged (untested as of yet), but I'm wondering if I will be able to do anything once I'm connected or will my queries just time out?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to most stuff in theory as per this MS article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595.aspx ; but I would imagine if the server isn't responding what so ever you still might run into issues. You should be able to at least run diagnostic commands (DMV's) and troubleshoot what is pegging your server.

Answer (score 0):

One issue on a stressed SQL Server box is the memory pressure. Parts of the OS have been paged to disk and there isn't enough capacity to log onto the box.

I once read that you should enable this registry setting

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management]
"DisablePagingExecutive"=dword:00000001
```

It's still on [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757875(WS.10).aspx) for Windows Server 2003 but maybe it's [complete horlicks](https://serverfault.com/questions/12150/does-the-disablepagingexecutive-registry-change-have-any-actual-effect) now